# JENKINS - GROOVY - PIPELINE: How to hide a password from logs when the password is retrieved during the build itself

Tags: jenkins, groovy, passwords, jenkins-pipeline, undefined

I'm trying to hide a password in Jenkins' logs.
The password is undefined at the start of the build.
It is retrieved during the build by reading a vault and used in a curl command.

Comment: If the curl command is in a sh step which most likely will be then you could add 'set +x' in the line above the curl command

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In the groovy file, i did put

- set +x
- get the password from the vault
- echo the default in a netrc file
- echo the password in the same netrc file
- echo the username in the same netrc file
- set -x
- and curl with the netrc file

so i can debug